# Separate equations of the pair of lines $x^2+2xy\sec\theta+y^2=0$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

> Find the separate equations of the lines $x^2+2xy\sec\theta+y^2=0$

**Attempt 1**

$$
x^2+2xy\sec\theta+y^2=0\\
\frac{x^2}{y^2}+2\frac{x}{y}\sec\theta+1=0\\
\frac{x}{y}=\frac{-2\sec\theta\pm\sqrt{4\sec^2\theta-4}}{2}=-\sec\theta\pm\tan\theta=\frac{-1\pm\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}\\
x\cos\theta=-y(1\pm\sin\theta)\\
x\cos\theta+y(1\pm\sin\theta)=0
$$

**Attempt 2**

$$
x^2+2xy\sec\theta+y^2=0\\
\frac{y^2}{x^2}+2\frac{y}{x}\sec\theta+1=0\\
\frac{y}{x}=\frac{-2\sec\theta\pm\sqrt{4\sec^2\theta-4}}{2}=-\sec\theta\pm\tan\theta=\frac{-1\pm\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}\\
y\cos\theta=-x(1\pm\sin\theta)\\
y\cos\theta+x(1\pm\sin\theta)=0
$$

Why do I seems to get different solutions for the lines in attempts 1 and 2 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align}
   \dfrac{-1 \pm \sin \theta}{\cos \theta}
   &= \dfrac{-1 \pm \sin \theta}{\cos \theta} \cdot 
      \dfrac{-1 \mp \sin \theta}{-1 \mp \sin \theta} \\
   &= \dfrac{1-\sin^2 \theta}{\cos \theta (-1 \mp \sin \theta)} \\
   &= \dfrac{\cos^2 \theta}{\cos \theta (-1 \mp \sin \theta)} \\
   &= \dfrac{\cos \theta}{-1 \mp \sin \theta} \\
\end{align}

Comment: ohh i can't believe i didn't see that. Thanks for the help.